# как наиболее грамотно распарсить командную строку?

Tags: c++, linux, c, bash, аргументы

Языки: C++, bash, C.

Мне надо распарсить опции командной строки. При этом, опции не должны быть позиционно зависимыми. Т е, если пользователь введет ключ `-a`, то программа должна получить ключ, даже если он расположен или сразу после argv[0], или прямо в argv[argc - 1]. Я не хочу ради этого приписывать кучу `if-else`, а у меня ещё и полно таких опций. Не подскажете решения более краткого и экономичного, чем `if-else` и `switch-case`?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону `boost::program_options` или `gengetopt`

Comment: `getopt` для простых командных строк.

Comment: [Parsing Program Options with Argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) -- мощная библиотека

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то для подобных целей я написал себе простую библиотечку и до сих пор пользуюсь ей в маленьких программках, когда не хочется тащить что-то монструозное.

Из того, что упоминали в комментариях, я рассматривал `boost.programm_options`, мне он показался раздутым для моих простых целей.
Также рассматривал другие популярные решения:

- boost.property_tree
- libconfig

Все они меня, как водится, чем-то не устроили.
То есть они все хорошие, но либо слишком абстрактные, либо слишком тяжелые, либо слишком мощные и т.п.

На гитхабе, где хостится мое решение, есть `Readme` с маленьким обоснованием, почему решил написать свое.
Ссылка: https://github.com/o2gy84/libproperty

Comment: Чем плох `getopt`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да вроде ничем не плох :)  
Впрочем, `getopt` реализует более императивный подход, в стиле plain C.